# In powershell script, test if "psexec" is installed

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script that will be used by many.  It uses the PSTools executable called "psexec".

How can I test at the beginning of the script to see if the user has psexec installed and then throw an error if they dont?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
$psexec = get-command psexec
if($psexec){
    #continue
}
```

`Get-Command` will throw exception if the command does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
$psExec = @(Get-Command psexec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
$psExecExists = $psExec.Length -gt 0
```

The `ErrorAction` and array constructor (`@(...)`) means `$psExec` will be an empty array is `psexec` is not found. This avoids exceptions and makes the check for existence very easy,